# Cloudberry Powershell scripts failing since version 4.6 (or later) - "Redirect location is empty"

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, cloudberry

A number of people have raised similar issues, but solutions suggested don't seem to help (including adding Set-CloudOption -PathStyle Path etc.)

I've been using multiple scripts based on the following example that have worked well for a number of years.  These scripts all fail when using any version of Cloudberry Explorer PRO above v4.5.1.98 (4.6..., 4.7... etc.), so I'm stuck using version 4.5.

**Example Script**:

```
add-pssnapin CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn

Set-CloudOption -UseSSL $true

Set-CloudOption -PermissionsInheritance "inheritall"

Set-CloudOption -ThreadCount 5

$s3 = Get-CloudS3Connection -UseSSL -Key kkk -Secret ssss

$dest = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -Path bucket/D/Data-Users

$local = Get-CloudFileSystemConnection

$source = $local | Select-CloudFolder \\server\D\Data-Users

$source | Copy-CloudSyncFolders $dest -CompareByContent -IncludeSubFolders -DeleteOnTarget -SSE -StorageClass standard
```

**Error Reported**:

> Select-CloudFolder : Redirect location is empty At line:1 char:15
>   + $dest = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -path bucket/D/Data-Users
>   +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Select-CloudFolder], Exceptio    n
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn
>   .Commands.SelectCloudFolder

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -PathStyle  - Path style if this flag is specified. VHost otherwise.

from here http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-s3-powershell.aspx

Thus correct would be:

```
Set-CloudOption -PathStyle VHost
```

Comment: Ahhh - thank you!  This was not required with older versions, and I understood that "VHost" was default if not specified. Working now!

Comment: Indeed the documentation is confusing. To clarify, VHost is *not* the default and has to be explicitly specified in your script as above.